# How to get Number from a text in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got a text as `Quantity      2` in this format .

How to extract number from the above variable .

I tried this way , but its displaing as NaN .

```
var lasth6= 'Quantity      2';
var number = parseInt(lasth6, 10);
alert(number);
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/10/

Could anybody please help . how to do this ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  remove non integer characters using:

```
.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' )
```

and then using `.parseInt()`:

```
parseInt(lasth6.replace( /[^\d.]/g, '' ), 10)
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4R292/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex

```
var regex = /\d+/;
alert(lasth6.match(regex));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9RXA/)

**OR**

Simply you can replace all non digits with nothing.

```
alert(lasth6.replace(/^\D+/g, ''));
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8s4v7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   parseInt(lasth6.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
```

^ showing negation of 0-9 number means anything rather than 0-9. 'g' stand for global replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function for getting only integer part from string and then parse it as followed :

```
var id_attr_val = 71;
var lasth6= $("div#"+id_attr_val+".Topping-details h6:last").text(); // Quantity      2
var arr = lasth6.split('      ')
var number = parseInt(arr[arr.length - 1], 10);
alert(number);
```

[here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/14/)